TestKit / GradleRunner + Sonarqube: code shows up as not covered
I am building a gradle plugin.
This is plugin's configuration.
build.gradle.kts
plugins { 
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.4.1.3373"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.7.6"
}

dependencies {
    api(gradleApi())
}

PluginTest
val temporaryFolder = Files.newTemporaryFolder().apply { deleteOnExit() }
File(temporaryFolder, "settings.gradle.kts").writeText("")
File(temporaryFolder, "build.gradle.kts")
    .writeText(""" plugins { id("mycompany.plugin") } """)
GradleRunner.create()
    .withProjectDir(temporaryFolder)
    .withPluginClasspath()
    .withArguments("doSomething")
    .build()

Test executes fine, however Sonarqube dashboard shows that doSomething task code was not executed. Is there any configuration that may help to overcome this?
Thanks!
